# Does gatling reported response times include the response time from a hosted redis feeder?

Tags: scala, redis, gatling

For particular gatling load testing simulation, we have some data that we normalize and temporarily store in redis in order to feed our simulation scenario for each request that is made. This data is retrieved using the redis data feeder API in our simulation, gatling/scala code. We have redis running on a separate server. I am curious if the reported response times in the gatling results report includes the response time for each record that gets popped out of redis for each request that is built and executed during the simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the gatling feeder, then the time spent getting the records from Redis won't be reflected in your gatling results.

The only possible way that this would be included anywhere would be if you called .feed inside a group AND had useGroupDurationMetric = true in gatling.conf. Then the group duration would include the time taken to get the data from Redis